# Postfix/Courier - list known email accounts or addresses

Tags: email, imap, postfix, courier

I'm trying to set up an IMAP server. Its a new server in a migration.

I *thought* I completed all the steps from [Virtual mailboxes with courier-imap and postfix](http://dannorth.net/2007/09/09/virtual-mailboxes-with-courier-imap-and-postfix/), but apparently I have missed something. When I run the migration tool (`imapsync`) I am receiving the error:

```
Failure: error login on [debian-x2...] wuth user [jdoe@example.com] auth [LOGIN]: 2 NO Login failed
```

I believe the error is telling me that there's no user on the *new* system named `jdoe@example.com`. (Login to the old system succeeds).

How do I have `postfix` and `courier` list or print their users in an attempt to figure out which is not configured properly?

Comment: Unless you use a database it is not possible to list all email accounts. With `postfix` you can check whether a email account exist with `postmap`

Comment: Thanks clement. I'm beginning to thing courier is the wrong tool. Its not well documented, and the docs I am finding/using do not work...